# Yodlee IAV ExtendedInstantAccountVerification exception

Tags: yodlee

I am running SampleApplication for Yodlee IDV. I already created a catalog named yantra and got credentials. When I initiate IAV, it throws ExtendedInstantAccountVerificationInfo. I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

---

IAV Data Matching Menu

---

1. Initiate IAV (Includes MFA)
2. Show All Routing Numbers for the cobrand
3. Show Content Service Info for a Routing Number
4. Exit

Enter Choice : 1
Bank Account #: (For DAGBANK it is 503-1123) 503-1123
Routing # (for DAGBANK it is 999999989) 999999989
AccountType : (Checking is 2, Savings is 1) 2
CSID: (For DAGBANK it is 11195) 11195
    CobrandContext is valid (2 minutes old), using cached CobrandContext...
22059 
Please Enter Username: yantra.bank1

22058 
Please Enter Password: bank1

22058 
Please Enter Verify Password: bank1

Core Exception....
CoreExceptionFaultMessage
ExtendedInstantAccountVerificationInfo is null, try later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please provide me the API which is being used for IAV and also the SOAP URL which you are using?

My suggestion is to use below API for doing IAV

"ExtendedInstantVerificationDataService.addItemAndStartVerificationDataRequest(UserContext userContext, long contentServiceId, ArrayOfFieldInfo credentialFields, java.lang.String routingNumber, java.lang.String accountNumber) "

Regards
Shreyans

Comment: Is there any specific documentation for what should go in credentialFields, Specific value for userName or passWord?